# Swift: How to transition from Navigation Controller to Tab Bar Controler

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

SoI have a Tab bar based app, but which is supposed to go trough a login / Signup process first. The Signup and Login works fine and I was able to move to a new ViewController and set it to be the new root VC with a function 
`
func transitionToHome(){

```
    let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storybord.HomeViewController) as? homeViewController

    view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
    view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}`
```

This was all working fine and I decided to move along and start building the tabbed ui, thats when I ran intro problems. As seen in my [Main Storyboard can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFFQU.png), the structure is simple. How do I connect the Login and Signup Buttons with something else than a ViewController, so for example the Tab Bar Controller? I managed to get to one of the Tabs but that didn't cut it either because I would then lose the ability to navigate between them.. I am in my first days of swift so I would love to hear any tips. I bet its not that hard after all.

Right now I am trying to get it to work by giving my Tab Bar Controller a Storyboard ID which I am then looking for in my modified version of the code above. Since i cannot add a ViewController for the Tab Bar Controller I am then starting the Tab Bar Item I want to have as default, but this just gives me a black screen..

Comment: "How do I connect the Login and Signup Buttons with something else than a ViewController, so for example the Tab Bar Controller?" Can you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: a TabBarController *is* a view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey I found the issue. Thanks @Paulw11 for pointing out that a Tab Bar Viewcontroller can be used just like a normal view controller. The problem was the part "
as? MainViewController", this had to say as? UITabBarController and voila, it worked. For anyone in the future, thats how you do it.